# unable to load external CSS in html file

Tags: html, css, file

I am working on a front end project where my folder structure is :

```
FOLDER:BILL
   FOLDER:CSS_FILES
       file :style.css
   FOLDER:HTML_FILES
       file:index.html
       FOLDER:IMAGES
          image.png
```

This is how I load  CSS in my html file and it does not work .

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="BILL/CSS_FILES/style.css">
```

I don't understand why as I have included the whole path . Maybe I should insert the css folder in the html one where it should work but I would like to know if there is another solution .
Thank you in advance .

Comment: is your file css displayed in `<head>` tag?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it like:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="../CSS_FILES/style.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct href is "../CSS_FILES/style.css"

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included the whole path.

You've included a **relative** path.

Assuming the URL of the HTML document is `http://example.com/HTML_FILES/index.html` then `href="BILL/CSS_FILES/style.css"` will resolve to `http://example.com/HTML_FILES/BILL/CSS_FILES/style.css`.

If you want to start from `http://example.com/` then you need to use an **absolute path** which will start with a `/`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="/BILL/CSS_FILES/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of path. Absolute and relative.
So for absolute path, it should start with main directory, where as in relative path,the directories are according to your present working directory.
So the correct path is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="../CSS_FILES/style.css">
```